# Dynamically Clone Element when User Specifies amount? - JavaScript + HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible for a user to type in an `<input>` box the amount of an element they would like to be cloned and append on the page?

The problem is, when a user currently specifies the amount of elements to be cloned, the number of elements is greater than that wanting to be cloned on the second click. Also, is it possible to hide the original element to be cloned within HTML and CSS? Please find attached the code below and the [JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/InnovativeDave/34kbz4sh/).

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
    var e = $('.col');
    for (i=0;i<number;i++) {
      e.clone().insertAfter(e);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Specify Amount of Member Cards Required:<input placeholder="e.g. 2" type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">
<button id="btn" onclick="addinputFields()">Go</button>

<div>

</div>
<br>
<div class="col">Member Card</div>
```

Comment: So you want to hide previously cloned elements?

Comment: Hi, with the Javascript code it currently clones an existing element through identifying the class and cloning. Therefore, I only want to hide the original element the Javascript is copying from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight tweak on the HTML and Javascript.

Added a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/calebkang/bjrdq81s/1/) of the code below.

**HTML**

```
Specify Amount of Member Cards Required:

<input placeholder="e.g. 2" type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">
<button id="btn">Go</button>

<div id="colTemplate" class="col">Member Card</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* hide the template */
#colTemplate { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#btn').click(() => {
  let number = document.getElementById('member').value,
      container = $('#container'),
      template = $('#colTemplate'),
      currentNumber = container.children().length;

  if (currentNumber < number) {
    // Add clones
    for (let i = 0; i < number - currentNumber; i++) {
      let clone = template.clone(true);
      clone.attr('id', null);   // Remove the id from the clone
      container.append(clone);
    }
  } else if (number < currentNumber) {
    // Remove extras
    let extras = $('#container .col');
    for (let i = currentNumber - 1; i > number - 1; i--) {
      extras.eq(i).remove();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for contributing to this question. However, the problem with the following code is when the user attempts to add more elements dynamically the second time, there are more dynamic elements than originally specified. Is it possible to resolve these issues? Thank you!

Comment: @Dave, I updated the answer above. It had a few minor logic problems. They are now fixed. I've also added a link to a jsfiddle so you can see the code working there.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:first` selector to clone only the first

```
 $('.col:first').hide();
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var number = $("#member").val();
    var e = $('.col:first');
    $('.col').not('.col:first').remove();
    for (i=0;i<number;i++) {
      e.show().clone().insertAfter(e);
    }
    $('.col:first').hide();

});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/j4jmyh0q/